# Reservation vs Booking an online Course

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

I am unsure what word to use in the sentence. It is part of a system that we are releasing to the public so it has to be grammatically correct :)

The sentence in question is:

> Thank You for your booking. We will reserve a seat for 72 hours...

What I would like to know is, in the context of an online course, do you say "Thank You for your booking..." or "Thank You for your reservation"

I don't know if it's a US English vs UK English matter.

Comment: Courses are usually  *registered*. Thank you for registering...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of this site is that you have attempted some initial research on your own. Have you looked up the dictionary definitions of *reservation* and *booking*? Have you looked at online courses offered by other organizations to see what terminology they use? I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The example *Thank You for your booking. We will reserve a seat for 72 hours* invites endless confusion, at best.

If it was merely an *enquiry* then *Thank You for your enquiry* could be appropriate.

If it’s a *booking*, then *We will reserve a seat for 72 hours* is entirely inappropriate, and might get you sued in court.

To *reserve a seat for X hours* implies the service provider is waiting for confirmation but either a *booking* or a *reservation* is its own confirmation. This is made more obvious by your offering *Thank You for your reservation* as the alternative.

Please be sure there is no relevant difference between a *booking* and a *reservation*, but *to make a reservation* is a different thing than simply *to reserve*. I have no faint idea how the difference arose.

One meaning is exactly the same as *booking*, ie, *Please make a reservation for three seats on the Orient Express…* That's no tentative enquiry but a firm booking, against which money can be charged.

*Please reserve three seats on the Orient Express…* is not nearly so clear. It  might be a firm booking; it might be no more than tentative

The other meaning is indeed temporary, precisely as in your example: *We will reserve a seat for 72 hours* is not a firm booking. If the enquiry is not confirmed within the time specified, the seat will be lost. In some circumstances, any deposit will be lost with it.

It wouldn’t be impossible, but I doubt any of that differs between British and US American English.